# Rails 3 - link_to applying a style

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to apply a style to a link but Rails is generating the class HTML in such a way that it will not render the HTML in a standard way.

**Asset Pipeline is OFF**

How can I resolve this?

Thanks

**Here is the link_to code:**

```
<%= link_to "Create a New Account",  :action => "signup", :class =>"gray_button"  %>
```

**Generated Rails Output - (Does not apply the style)**

```
<a href="/login/signup?class=gray_button">Create a New Account</a><br />
```

**When I edit the HTML in Firebug like so it renders**

```
<a href="/login/signup" class="gray_button">Create a New Account</a><br />
```

Answer (score 0):

In Rails 3 you need to use a hash like so:

```
<%= link_to "Create a New Account",{:action => "signup" }, :class => "gray_button" %><br />
```

Answer (score 0):

In a rails app, you have an helper for your routes `rake routes`

```
<%= link_to "Create a New Account", signup_path , :class => "gray_button" %>
```